# Saving an icon on a jLabel as an Image on the hard disk

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have a an Image Icon generated in my code which i place it as an icon on a label as per the following code:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(barcode.drawBarcode());
jLabel36.setIcon(icon);
```

Now my problem is that how can i change the ImageIcon type to Image and save it on the hard disk. when i try to type cast ImageIcon to Image i get the following error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.ImageIcon cannot be cast to java.awt.Image

Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this task both type casting and saving the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`getImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage%28%29):

```
// get image from imageicon
Image image = icon.getImage();

// cast it to bufferedimage
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;

try {
    // save to file
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(buffered, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So long as you have a reference to ImageIcon, otherwise you will need to paint the icon onto the graphics context of the buffered image